# Cannot email multiple users in SharePoint Group

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I'm using SharePoint 2007 and when I select all users in a group(i.e 20 users), the email function just hangs.  However, if I select 2 users in the same group, the email function works. This is what I do, go into Site Settings/People and Groups>select the appropriate group>select all>click Actions tab>Email Users.  Are there limitations to how many users can go through an email?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that helped me over come that issue. If you go into your internet options in IE, select security tab, then on internet settings. Disable/unchecked protected mode. All other zone was disabled except there.
This help me email about 30 users in the group instead of 15. Hope this helps